# Sammy.js does not get the location in Internet Explorer

Tags: sammy.js

Is there some explanation as when executing the following :

```
location.hash = "#/";
```

it works well in firefox (19.0.2) but not in IE (10.0.92).

In firefox it returns to the "homepage", whereas in IE it does nothing. No error shown either.

this code comes from this function :

```
self.addStoreItem = function () {
            var data = appFsMvc.utility.serializeObject( $("#StoreItemForm") );
            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/StoreItems",
                data: JSON.stringify( data ),
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json"
            })
            .done(function () {
                toastr.success( "You have successfully created a new StoreItem!", "Success!" );
                self.StoreItems.push(data);
                location.hash = "#/";
            })
            .fail(function () {
                toastr.error( "There was an error creating your new StoreItem", "<sad face>" );
            });
        };
```

and the code to manage sammy.js :

```
appFsMvc.App = function( StoreItemsViewModel ) {
        return $.sammy( "#content", function () {
            var self = this;

            this.use( Sammy.Cache );
            this.StoreItemViewModel = StoreItemsViewModel;

            this.renderTemplate = function ( html ) {
                self.$element().html( html );
                ko.applyBindings( self.StoreItemViewModel );
            };

            // display all StoreItems
            this.get( "#/", function() {
                this.render("/Templates/StoreItemDetail.htm", {}, function ( html ) {
                    self.renderTemplate( html );
                });
            });

            // display the create StoreItems view
            this.get( "#/create", function() {
                this.render("/Templates/StoreItemCreate.htm", {}, function ( html ) {
                    self.renderTemplate( html );
                });
            });
        });
    };
```

I have tried to use firbuglite, but this latter ends up in crash when I try using it on my website. Developers tool of IE do not show any errors.

[EDIT]

found how to enable firebuglite  using [getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Debug](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4927) instead of stable release :

the console is giving me these hints :

- when clicking on CreateNewItem

> [Thu Mar 21 15:38:11 UTC+0100 2013] #content runRoute get /#/create
>
> GET /Templates/StoreItemCreate.htm 200 OK   5ms
>
> POST /api/StoreItems 200 OK  7ms

whereas doing the same in Firefox gives me :

> [Thu Mar 21 2013 15:40:41 GMT+0100] #content runRoute get /#/create
>
> GET http://myLocalHost:9501/Templates/StoreItemCreate.htm 200 OK 1ms
>
> POST http://myLocalHost:9501/api/StoreItems 200 OK 27ms
>
> [Thu Mar 21 2013 15:40:46 GMT+0100] #content runRoute get /#/

I can see in IE the url in the adress bar giving the correct url http://localhost:9501/#/create and then http://localhost:9501/#/ after posting my form.
[/EDIT]